# Wandering Robot - in Kickstart got WA

Tags: java, algorithm

I try to write a short solution for a Google Kick Start question in 2020 Round B and always get a WA. I tried to figure out where was wrong but nothing found. I even download other's passed code and wrote a dataset creator to let two programs run and compare the result, but after running more than 100,000 groups of data, nothing different has been found. I'm kind of crazy now, could you help me to check out what's wrong in my code, please?

Here is the question:

> Jemma is competing in a robotics competition. The challenge for today
> is to build a robot that can navigate around a hole in the arena.
>
> The arena is a grid of squares containing W columns (numbered 1 to W
> from left to right) and H rows (numbered 1 to H from top to bottom).
> The square in the x-th column and y-th row is denoted (x, y). The
> robot begins in the top left square (1,1) and must navigate to the
> bottom right square (W, H).
>
> A rectangular subgrid of squares has been cut out of the grid. More
> specifically, all the squares that are in the rectangle with top-left
> square (L, U) and bottom-right square (R, D) have been removed.
>
> Jemma did not have much time to program her robot, so it follows a
> very simple algorithm: If the robot is in the rightmost column, it
> will always move to the square directly below it. Otherwise, If the
> robot is in the bottommost row, it will always move to the square
> directly right of it. Otherwise, The robot will randomly choose to
> either move to the square directly to the right, or to the square
> directly below it with equal probability.
>
> Jemma passes the challenge if her robot avoids falling into the hole
> and makes it to the square (W, H). What is the probability she passes
> the challenge?
>
> **Input** 
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T
> test cases follow. Each test case consists of a single line containing
> W, H, L, U, R, and D.
>
> **Output** 
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y,
> where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is a real
> number between 0 and 1 inclusive, the probability that Jemma passes
> the challenge.
>
> y will be considered correct if it is within an absolute or relative
> error of 10-5 of the correct answer. See the FAQ for an explanation of
> what that means, and what formats of real numbers we accept.
>
> **Limits Time limit:**
> 15 seconds per test set. Memory limit: 1GB. 1 ≤ T ≤
> 100. 1 ≤ U ≤ D ≤ H. 1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ W. Neither the top-left nor bottom-right squares will be missing.
>
> Test set 1 1 ≤ W ≤ 300. 1 ≤ H ≤ 300.
>
> Test set 2 1 ≤ W ≤ 105. 1 ≤ H ≤ 105.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sets = scan.nextInt();
        for(int q = 0; q < sets; q++){
            int rows = scan.nextInt();
            int cols = scan.nextInt();
            double[][] board = new double[rows + 1][cols + 1];
            int leftx = scan.nextInt();
            int lefty = scan.nextInt();

            int rightx = scan.nextInt();
            int righty = scan.nextInt();

            if((rightx == rows && righty == cols) || (leftx == 1 && rightx == 1)){
                System.out.println("Case #" + (q + 1) + ": " + 0.0);
                continue;
            }
            board[1][1] = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
                for(int j = 1; j < cols; j++){
                    if((i == rightx && j >= lefty && j <= righty) || (j == righty && i >= leftx && i <= rightx)){
                        continue;
                    }
                    board[i + 1][j] += board[i][j] / 2;
                    board[i][j + 1] += board[i][j] / 2;
                }
            }
            for(int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
                if(cols == righty && i >= leftx && i <= rightx){
                    continue;
                }
                board[i + 1][cols] += board[i][cols];
            }
            for(int i = 1; i < cols; i++){
                if(rows == rightx && i >= lefty && i <= righty){
                    continue;
                }
                board[rows][i + 1] += board[rows][i];
            }

            System.out.printf("Case #%d: %.10f\n", q + 1, board[rows][cols]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks to find the probability, *y is a real number between 0 and 1 inclusive*. Your code computes the number of paths safely leading to the bottom-right corner, an integer. No wonders it is a wrong answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But in my code, the output is the probability between 0 and 1, not the safe paths, as I set the probability of point (1,1) as 1 and calculate the probability of every single point in the board, and at the last, output the probability of the right bottom point.